# powershell create scheduled task without version dependent

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Am trying to create scheduled task on Windows 2008 R2 with the below method, since this is the method will not depend on any of the powershell version.

```
$createTask = "schtasks /create /f /tn `"facter`" /tr `"C:\Ruby193\bin\facter.bat -y > C:\mcollective\facts.yaml`" /ru `"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`" /RL HIGHEST /sc daily /st 00:00"
Invoke-Expression $createTask
```

This task will refresh the mcollective facts yaml file with last information for every 24hours. I have created this task from my AD account login (I have full administrator privilege) and this task has to be run with `SYSTEM` user account.

But its not running properly and on Last run result column am seeing message as `(0x1)`.

If I create the same task to run as my AD user account then it runs properly.

Comment: Use another set of quotes around the `facter.bat` file path to distinguish it from the argument strings: ``/tr `"'C:\Ruby193\bin\facter.bat' -y > C:\mcollective\facts.yaml`"``

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hmmm it doesn't help